# mongoengine connection connectionerror with django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mlab, restframeworkmongoengine

I am trying to build Django rest framework with MongoDB. So in my local its working. But in production, i'm using MongoLab as DB backend. But i'm not able make DB connection. I'm keep on getting DB connection authentication error.

```
command SON([('authenticate', 1), ('user', u'XXXXX'), ('nonce', u'XXXXX'), ('key', u'XXXXXX')]) failed: auth failed
```

Connection establishment code in settings file:

```
MONGODB_DATABASES = {
    "name": "XXXXX",
    "host": "XXX.mlab.com",
    "port": 33212,
    "username": "XXXX",
    "password": "XXXX"
}

mongoengine.connect(
    db=MONGODB_DATABASES['name'],
    host=MONGODB_DATABASES['host'],
    port=MONGODB_DATABASES['port'],
    username=MONGODB_DATABASES['username'],
    password=MONGODB_DATABASES['password'],
)
```

The MongoLab mongo version : `mongod version: 3.6.6 (MMAPv1)`. Correct me what i did wrong

Comment: Hi Sakthi - have you updated your auth credentials for production?

Comment: Yeah, i created a new user

Comment: And, as frustrating as this is, are you sure you've entered the new credentials correctly both sides? (both when you registered a new db user and when you set this somewhere in your codebase)

Comment: Yeah, i'm sure **Updated in both sides**

Comment: Without any typos? Try setting host to either the IP address of your production server or `localhost` - it might be that the domain name doesn't resolve for that particular port...

Comment: **Yeah** i'm damm sure

Comment: Double check for me...add a new db user with an easy to type/remember password...

Comment: @MichealJRoberts I did it for you. Still it's not working

Comment: Ok, and the database name is correct and you have set host to localhost? Has the user you've setup got permission to read and write to that database?

Comment: Localhost no, i'm using mLab cloud. So i'm using that url and default database name of mLab

Comment: Hmmm....you have the database on a production server?

Comment: Can you read the question one more time and it's not credentials problem. It's some authentication parameter problem.

Comment: Hi Sakthi - the authorisation can fail because of incorrect credentials. You may have the right user credentials (username and password) but that user might not have authorisation to access that database. In production environments, what’s often the case is that you can’t access the database remotely and need to access from localhost.

Comment: mlab should have given you all of the credentials information you needed, if you’re adamant this is all correct then you may need to contact mlab support.

Comment: No, i tried from terminal. I'm able to access the collection, that i created manually from mLab website.

Comment: I think you might need to speak to mLab - what version of Django are you using?

Comment: python = 2.7.15
Django==1.11.7
djangorestframework==3.7.3

Comment: Check if all of this is compatible with the mongoDB wrapper/driver you're using...have you tried `djongo` as well?

Comment: djongo need python 3. That's why i moved to django rest framework mongoengine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by connecting the mongoengine with mLab like this

```
mongoengine.connect(
    "DB-Name",
    host="mongodb://username:password@XXXXX.mlab.com:33252/db-name"
)
```

Thanks [Micheal J Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10261970/micheal-j-roberts)